# Cannot set the default app to open PNG in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, file-association

I want to change the default app to open PNG files in my laptop. Usually I can do that by right clicking, click "open with", click "choose another app", and at the bottom of the modal window there will be a checkbox "Always use this app to open..." to change the default app.

But in this laptop the "always use..." checkbox doesn't appear in the context menu:
[image]

I tried opening Settings > Apps > Default apps. At the bottom I chose "choose defaults by file type". I searched for "png" in the search box, but it didn't show normal PNG, just Azure Information Protection Viewer:
[image]

I tried opening Apps > Default apps > IrfanView 32-bit, the application that I want to set as default viewer. PNG is not available there either:
[image]

PNG is not available in Windows Photo Viewer either:
[image]

When I double click a PNG, the application that opens is "Print Pictures":
[image]

But there is no apps called "Print Pictures" in my laptop.

This happens on JPG as well.

I have tried to "reset all default apps" from the bottom of the "Default apps" page as well. No luck.

How do I set IrfanView as the default app to open PNG under this condition?

Comment: Using Apps, Default Apps, Choose defaults by File Type works fine here. Windows 11 Pro V22H2.   Run DISM / SFC and see if that helps.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John thanks for the suggestions, I have done them but PNG option is still not showing up.

Comment: You may then need to do a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.   Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

Comment: Also, make a new, test Windows User Account and log into the new Account.  Can you set PNG associations in the new account?  If so, your original Account profile is damaged. The easiest and fastest way to fix this is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @EndyTjahjono, did you ever manage to solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @JacquesBosch no. I installed Microsoft Photos and it could take over from Print Pictures, but that's as far as I got. But this is a company laptop and IT installed all kinds of things in it. Pretty sure the cause is one of those IT apps.

Comment: Mm. Ok. My problems started with Photos being the boss already. Mine is a personal laptop, so it doesn't have all the IT installed type stuff.

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue as well

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem.

This can be resolved by open PowerShell as an administrator and removing the Microsoft Photos app from the machine. Without that app hijacking my defaults, IrfanView was the next default candidate.

PowerShell command:

```
get-appxpackage *photos* | remove-appxpackage
```

Comment: So, instead of modifying the reference, you just delete the existing one? Looks like a lousy solution to me.

Comment: The solution is crude, but I would argue not lousy. I have no use for Microsoft Photos as an app, which is why I installed IrfanView in the first place. Removing an app I never want to encounter is a win in my book. 

I am having difficulty imagining a situation in which I would regret my solution. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Removing default apps of any kind in Windows earns an upvote.

Comment: The suggestion does not solve the problem, unfortunately.