# How to set MS-Excel as default program to a .csv file in Windows 11 pro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am not able to set MS-Excel as default program for a .csv file in Windows 11 pro. I have tried many ways, but not able to do it.

I have to either choose "open with" option or first open MS-Excel and then open the .csv file. I have tried the following ways and attached the screenshot of what I got:

1. Changing default app through Properties: I tried simply opening "Properties" by right clicking the *ViewSchedule-ASIDATA.csv* file and I got this:
   [file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKyWK.png). There is no option of "Change".
2. Setting a default by file type of link: I tried to set a default app for *.csv* file but there is no such file type displaying:
   [Set a default by file type or link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm5c5.png).
3. Setting default for Applications: I tried to set a default file type for Excel Application but there is no .csv file type displaying:
   [Set defaults for applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHoez.png).
4. Selecting app through "*Open with*" option: I tried "*Open with*" option too but I'm able to open this file just once. Every time I have to repeat this option to open the .csv file.
   [Open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW9yw.png)

What is the issue I'm not able to understand, I have tried re-installing the MS-Office program but not able to set default app for .csv file type. How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting CSV to open with Excel works fine on several Windows 11 Pro machines here.  Did you make some other settings changes in some other way?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik are you suggesting the Photos app is hijacking, or Notepad, or something else? The marked dupe seems to be more specific and possibly note a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot set the default app to open PNG in Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1750358/cannot-set-the-default-app-to-open-png-in-windows-11)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on a CSV file. Select "Open with" then click on "Choose another app". Find "Microsoft Excel", then choose "Always".

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

- Run *Start > Default Programs*
- Click on Excel in the list
- Click on `.csv`
- You can now choose Excel in the dialog with the "Set default" button.